# How to associate models of two different sailsJs project?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline, sails-postgresql

I have a sailsJs project that manages login for different type of users i.e. user type1,user type2 etc. I have another sailsJs project that manages the services provided by these users, so i need to associate the user type model with the services they provide. What is the best way to achieve this? Basically if somehow i get the reference of all the user models in the other project, this can be achieved. I read about installable hooks but i am not sure how can i use it and there is not good tutorial available to use the same. Please guide me the way in which i can achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it matter how many projects you have? Just use one database from where you can get latest data. Or implement OAuth2.0 on each of projects.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-inject

much the same question here

[How to create a normal sails model without being in the models folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21085624/how-to-create-a-normal-sails-model-without-being-in-the-models-folder)